# How do I handle custom errors, globally, in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using a library in my application which regularly returns tuples of `{:ok, value}` or `{:error, error}`. In the cases where we assume there may be an error (such as a user input), we're handling those cases explicitly. For all other cases, I would prefer to assume they will be properly handled and if not, have the failure case be handled with a redirect.

I started trying to solve this issue by using a function:

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = client.user_show(conn.assigns.endpoint, id) |> get_value(conn)
  # rest of method omitted
end

def get_value({:ok, value}, _conn), do: value

def get_value({:error, value}, conn)  do
  conn
  |> put_flash(:error, "Client error")
  |> redirect(to: "/")
  |> halt
end
```

This seemed like a good idea, but unfortunately, the conn was still continuing, despite the halt. This makes sense because the code path didn't split.

So it seems like the better solution would be to implement this function to raise a specific error and then try to resolve it globally.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to handle an error at the global level with Phoenix. The only possible option I see is using the `ErrorView`, but I don't want just to show an error, I want to redirect appropriately depending on the error.

Am I missing something or is this not possible currently in Phoenix?

Answer (score 0):

The `halt` function doesn't actually provide any branching logic. It only sets `conn`s private field `halted` to `true`. This makes sure that other **plugs** will not process it further, but rest of the action will process it and override the `halted` field.

The solution is to move this function to a plug.

```
def client_error_plug(conn) do
  user = client.user_show(conn.assigns.endpoint, id) |> get_value(conn)
  case user do
    {:ok, user} ->
      assign(conn, :current_user, user)
    {:error, reason} -> 
      conn
      |> put_flash(:error, "Client error")
      |> redirect(to: "/")
      |> halt
  end
end
```

and in your controller just put"

```
plug :client_error_plug when action in [:show, ...]
```

It probably makes sense to give this plug a more meaningful name, but it depends on the application logic :) Now you can be sure that you have the user in assigns, because if it is not there the redirect will kick in.